# Why would specific SQL have a recordcount of -1?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ado

I've picked up some code. The record set is opened as follows...

```
rs.open sql, db, 3, 3, 1
```

With the following SQL, the record set's RecordCount property is correct.

```
SELECT client.id, 
       client.NAME, 
       postcode, 
       locationx, 
       locationy, 
       NULL     AS blacklisted, 
       '&nbsp;' AS distance 
FROM   client 
       LEFT JOIN county 
              ON client.county = county.id 
WHERE  hidden = 0 
       AND client.NAME LIKE '%' 
       AND ( address LIKE '%%' 
              OR county.NAME LIKE '%%' 
              OR postcode LIKE '%%' 
              OR phone LIKE '%%' 
              OR fax LIKE '%%' ) 
ORDER  BY client.NAME
```

Where as with the following beast, the RecordCount property is -1.

```
SELECT          booking.id, 
                booking.site, 
                site.NAME, 
                booking.client, 
                client.NAME AS clientname, 
                booking.confirmed, 
                Count(appointment.id)                   AS apps, 
                Sum(Cast(appointment.confirmed AS INT)) AS conf, 
                dates.[date]                            AS startdate, 
                h.hoursfull, 
                h.hours, 
                d.overdue, 
                e.soon 
FROM            booking 
LEFT OUTER JOIN site 
ON              booking.site = site.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dates 
ON              booking.id = dates.booking 
LEFT OUTER JOIN appointment 
ON              dates.id = appointment.[date] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN client 
ON              booking.client = client.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                ( 
                SELECT          booking, 
                                Sum(dates.hours)    AS hours, 
                                Sum(apps1.hourssum) AS hoursfull 
                FROM            dates 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                                ( 
                                            SELECT   [date], 
                                                    Sum(hours) AS hourssum 
                                            FROM     appointment 
                                            GROUP BY [date] ) AS apps1 
                ON              dates.id = apps1.[date] 
                GROUP BY        booking ) h 
ON              booking.id = h.booking 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                ( 
                       SELECT 1 AS overdue) d 
ON              dates.[date] <= Getdate() 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                ( 
                       SELECT 1 AS soon) e 
ON              dates.[date] <= Dateadd(hh, 48, Getdate()) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                ( 
            SELECT DISTINCT a.booking 
            FROM            ( 
                                            SELECT          dates.booking, 
                                                            Sum(apps2.hourssum) AS filled,
                                                            sum(dates.hours)   AS hours
                                            FROM            dates 
                                            LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                                                            ( 
                                                                        SELECT   [date],
                                                                                sum(hours) AS hourssum
                                                                        FROM     appointment
                                                                        GROUP BY [date] ) AS apps2
                                            ON              dates.id = apps2.[date] 
                                            GROUP BY        dates.booking )a 
            WHERE           ( 
                                            filled < hours) 
            OR              ( 
                                            filled IS NULL) )b 
ON              b.booking = booking.id 
WHERE           ( 
                                booking.hidden = 0) 
AND             booking.client = 2543 
AND             booking.confirmed = 1 
AND             ((( 
                SELECT TOP 1 
                    dates.id 
                FROM            dates 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN appointment 
                ON              dates.id = appointment.[date] 
                WHERE           ( 
                                dates.booking = booking.id)
                GROUP BY        dates.id, 
                                dates.booking 
                ORDER BY        dates.booking) = dates.id)
                OR              dates.id IS NULL) 
GROUP BY        booking.id, 
                booking.site, 
                site.NAME, 
                booking.confirmed, 
                dates.[date], 
                booking.client, 
                client.NAME, 
                h.hoursfull, 
                h.hours, 
                d.overdue, 
                e.soon 
ORDER BY        startdate
```

I can repeat this behaviour by switching the SQL around just before the same call to "open".

Comment: Does your second SQL statement run without error in SSMS?

Comment: Yes. It returns results to the app, but the code only shows the first page because it doesn't think there are any more results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my code for opening the record set from...

```
rs.open sql, db, 3, 3, 1
```

to...

```
rs.open sql, db, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
```

Much gratitude to [this](http://www.adopenstatic.com/faq/recordcounterror.asp) site.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using an [ADO recordset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681510(v=vs.85).aspx), which I suspect you are, you must use a static or keyset cursor type, if you want to access the [RecordCount property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676701(v=vs.85).aspx).

Take from MSDN

> The cursor type of the Recordset object affects whether the number of
>   records can be determined. The RecordCount property will return -1 for
>   a forward-only cursor; the actual count for a static or keyset cursor;
>   and either -1 or the actual count for a dynamic cursor, depending on
>   the data source.

**EDIT**

It would help if I'd fully read your question!  On larger more complex queries it is possible for the RecordCount to return -1, even with the correct cursor type.  This can happen for a number of reasons.  One example is the recordset is still populating as you start to use it.  Try jumping to the final record and then querying the recordcount .

Comment: Whichever configuration I'm using, it works with one SQL query but not with the other. Surely there's something about the query that's stopping it from working?

Comment: Apologies I misunderstood the question.  You are using the correct cursor type (Static = 3).  See added comments above.

Comment: I tried "MoveLast" after the call to open the recordset and it says, "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server: Rowset does not support fetching backward."

Comment: You might not be getting the cursor type you have requested.  Try adding this:  *Debug.Print rs.CursorType*.  If it returns anything other than 3  the type has changed, to one that doesn't support the RecordCount or MoveLast property.  You can try to force the issue by setting the CursorLocation = adUseClient.

Comment: It outputs the value 0. I suppose I will have to do a separate count query.

Comment: ADO cannot always serve up the cursor type you want.  When this occurs you have two choices.  Manually count the records or refactor the query.  Wrapping in a view/table function could help.

Comment: I've moved this code from a server where the recordcount property worked to a new server, where it doesn't work. Why would ADO work differently? Did they make multiple version which didn't work the same?

Comment: There are [multiple versions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676506(v=vs.85).aspx), the last of which was released back in 2004. If you are running ADO from the client then the version will always be the same (example VBA that connects to either the new or old server). When running from the server this could be an issue (example Classic ASP). But given the age of the last release it is more likely another server property has changed.

Comment: Where can I find out about ADO configuration? Could it be a SQL Server issue?